Is there a bias in linear least squares when all measurements have noise?
Imagine that we have a linear dependence $y = kx$. However our measurements $(\hat x_i, \hat y_i)$ have noise in both $x$ and $y$
$\hat x_i = x_i +\nu_i \ , \qquad \hat y_i = y_i +\varepsilon_i \ , \qquad i=\{1,..., n\}$
As I understand, in linear least squares method (LLS) it is assumed that only $y$ measurements have noise, right? Then if I try to apply LLS-formula with noisy data I get the tangent
$k = \frac{\langle \hat x \hat y\rangle}{\langle \hat x^2\rangle} =
\frac{\langle (x +\nu)(y +\varepsilon)\rangle}{\langle (x +\nu)^2\rangle} =
\frac{\langle (xy +\nu y+ x\varepsilon +\nu\varepsilon)\rangle}{\langle x^2 +2x\nu+\nu^2\rangle}
=\frac{\langle x y\rangle}{\langle x^2\rangle + \langle \nu^2 \rangle}$
where I have assumed that noise terms are not correlated with each other and with actual measurements. Therefore it seems that this estimate of $k$ will be wrong if we have noise in measurements of $x$. Is that right or I made a mistake somewhere in my reasoning? Is there a way to derive a formula for unbiased tangent? (Pointing to an available textbook is also OK).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-least-squares?tab=Votes

@SextusEmpiricus Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I wanted. Do you want to post it as a regular answer?
